# How to split the string into 2 with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, split

I am having these strings.

```
"LAKDOER 567-85 06D-1F"
"QRT1 35-43 459-70 D"
"50201 WSCFVGH 133 9H "
"STREE VDERYG 8C LOP"
"GG-STAR THIEOR- WL-515-67-26548H-9"
```

I want to split all the strings and need output like this.

```
["LAKDOER", "567-85 06D-1F"]
["QRT1",  "35-43 459-70 D"]
["50201 WSCFVGH", "133 9H "]
["STREE VDERYG", "8C LOP"]
["GG-STAR THIEOR-", "WL-515-67-26548H-9"]
```

Comment: What are the rules?

Comment: "string".split(" ", 1)

Comment: What are the conditions for the split to occur?

Comment: String should be splitted If a word after space starts with number or with 2 characters (like: WL in **"GG-STAR THIEOR- WL-515-67-26548H-9"**)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `re.split()` function and specific regex pattern:

```
import re

lst = ["LAKDOER 567-85 06D-1F", "QRT1 35-43 459-70 D", "50201 WSCFVGH 133 9H ", 
       "STREE VDERYG 8C LOP", "GG-STAR THIEOR- WL-515-67-26548H-9"
       ]

pat = re.compile(r'\s(?=[a-z-]*[0-9])', re.I)
for s in lst:
    print(pat.split(s, 1))
```

The output:

```
['LAKDOER', '567-85 06D-1F']
['QRT1', '35-43 459-70 D']
['50201 WSCFVGH', '133 9H ']
['STREE VDERYG', '8C LOP']
['GG-STAR THIEOR-', 'WL-515-67-26548H-9']
```

---

- `re.I` - regex flag, tells to match case-insensitively
- `\s(?=[a-z-]*[0-9])` - matches whitespace character `\s` followed by character sequence with mandatory number(s) `[0-9]` and optional `[a-z-]*` sequence (ensured by positive lookahead assertion `(?=...)`)

Comment: Thank you so much @RomanPerekhrest. This is exectly what I was looking for. I have similar questions for my work, Can you please explain me how does re.compile(r'\s(?=[a-z-]*[0-9])', re.I) works ?

Comment: It didn't worked for string "U. OPERTER 4-5". Output I get is "U. OPERTER
" instead of ['U. OPERTER', '4-5']. Any idea for this ?

Comment: I am sorry, I missed that earlier.

Comment: @Shadkhan, that's not true: I've tested and it gave me `['U. OPERTER', '4-5']`